# Preventing multiple objects from being printed

Tags: java, inheritance, printing, polymorphism, frequency

For my final CS180 project we have been given the task of creating a program that randomly generates some perishable and nonperishable items that would be found in a grocery cart and then printing a receipt for a customer.

The problem I am running into is finding a way to check the frequency of an item being created and preventing the item from printing multiple times on a receipt. For example, if someone buys 5 peaches the I want the output to be Peach $.99 X 5, total $4.95, instead of printing peach 5 times. Any suggestions?

The classes I have are Item (a super class of Perishable and Nonperishable), Perishable (creates perishable items) and nonperishable (nonperishable items and also figures their tax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to store all items, mapping Item to quantity.

So something like

```
HashMap<Item,Integer> receipt = new HashMap<Item,Integer>();
```

will be you receipt data structure.

And to to check if your `receipt` already has a particular item, say `i`, you would have

```
if (receipt.containsKey(i){
    receipt.get(i) += 1; // increment qantity
    // do other stuff to total, taxes etc.
} else { // this is the first time this kind of item is being added
    receipt.put(i, new Integer(1)); // so put it in the map
}
```

This way you can avoid duplicates (all keys in HashMaps are unique).

You would of course have to implement the `equals` method in your `Item` class (for example, items are equal when their names are equal) to let the HashMap know when two Items are equal (because when it performs the `contains` check, it tests for equality using the object's `equals` method).